# How many characters does string class in c++ support?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maximum length of a std::basic_string<_CharT> string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479459/maximum-length-of-a-stdbasic-string-chart-string)

I would like to know how many characters does string class in c++ support.

thanks..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
std::string s;
s.max_size();
```

That should tell you what that max size is.

Comment: +1 -- beat me to it by 2 seconds! :-)

Answer (score 0):

according to http://www.idinews.com/string3.html

> The std::string class supports varying length strings with no length limit.

Answer (score 0):

I am lead to believe that the size of a std::string object is limited to size of an unsigned integer on the architecture of your system. I would assume this since the length of the string is stored as a [size_t](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstddef/size_t/) value.